# ModuleNotFoundError When running own Project installed from PyPi using Setuptools and Wheels

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

When I install one of my own Python applications from PyPi, it fails to run citing

> File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/refrapt/refrapy.py", line 20, in 
> from classes import (
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classes'.

I have the following directory layout in my local area:

```
/refrapt
  setup.py
  /refrapt
    classes.py
    helpers.py
    refrapt.conf
    refrapt.py
    settings.py
    __init__.py
```

To build the project, I'm using `setuptools`, running the following command:
`python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
This builds and works happily enough, and I'm able to upload the resulting `/dist`.

I then install the project using `pip3 install refrapt`. When I run it using `refrapt`, I get the error  `ModuleNotFoundError` above.

When I run the development code locally, it runs fine, but installed via pip, it is failing. I assume it's a problem with my setup.py, but this is my first time and I haven't really a clue what is correct. I tried adding the **init**.py (which is empty) as suggested by some python docs, but to no avail. The contents of setup.py are as follows:

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

setup(
    name='Refrapt',
    version='0.1.5',
    description='A tool to mirror Debian repositories for use as a local mirror.',
    python_requires='>=3.9',
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'Click >= 7.1.2',
        'Colorama >= 0.4.4',
        'tqdm >= 4.60.0',
        'wget >= 3.2',
        'filelock >= 3.0.12'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation",
        "Topic :: System :: Archiving :: Mirroring"
    ],
    keywords=['Mirror', 'Debian', 'Repository'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        refrapt=refrapt:refrapt
    ''',
)
```

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate. I'm out of my depth on this one, and haven't been able to find an answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
from classes import …
```

In Python 2 this was relative import — the statements imports `classes` from the current directory of the importing module.

But in Python 3 it was changed to absolute import. The import fails because there is no a global module or a package named `classes`. You need to convert the import to absolute or relative. Either

```
from refrapt.classes import …
```

or

```
from .classes import …
```

Comment: Ah, so that has worked on my Ubunto box where I've installed the app. However, in my development environment (on Windows), when I make those changes, it complains: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'refrapt.classes'; 'refrapt' is not a package. I have it installed using `pip install -e .`

Comment: Can you just `import refrapt`? If not — make sure `pip install` runs under same Python you do import. Different Pythons have different set of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially I've found out the answer to my question, but it's not the answer I wanted.

I spun up a virtual environment, and installed an application that I've used before via `pip`. When I went to run the app, I got the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`.

I tried to run it manually via the `.py` file by using `python .\.venv\Lib\site-packages\app\cli.py`, which resulting in the same error.

Seems to be something about the environment setup in Windows VS Code that just doesn't operate the same as on a Linux machine.

I guess I'll just have to remove the "`refrapt.`" prefix from `import` statements when developing locally, and then add it back when pushing to GitHub.